# Trying to get local list using 'dbcontext.tablename.local' throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am simply checking if the user already exist in local source, I have a check if the 'dbcontext.tablename.local' is null then skip. Control passes this if condition then throws error "The object reference is not set to an instance"

When I debug and check the value of 'dbcontext.tablename.local' then it shows "The function evaluation requires all threads to run" and the error thrown after executing this line is "The object reference is not set to an instance".

I am not sure what is null here as if I click on reevaluate icon in quick watch I can see the records in the local list.

```
User user = null;
if (userDBContext.User.Local != null && userDBContext.User.Local.Count() > 0 && userDBContext.User.Local.Any(u => u.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()))
    user = userDBContext.User.Local.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower());
```

also tried below code,

```
if (userDBContext.User.Local != null && userDBContext.User.Local.ToList().Count() > 0 && userDBContext.User.Local.ToList().Any(u => u.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()))
    user = userDBContext.User.Local.ToList().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower());
```

Comment: You must provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Gusman I have edited my question, please see if it makes the question clear. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code, in cases like yours the best is to split the conditions into nested ifs to debug where exactly the error is produced. Maybe u.Email is null?

Comment: @Gusman there were so many records in the db where email is not supposed to null but there was one record with null value (maybe manually inserted), Deleted it and now it works